# What is wrong with this code? program that outputs minimum, maximum and average of integers in C using Array

Tags: c

```
/*C program that outputs minimum, maximum and average of integers*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
int i,a[5],min,max;
float avg;
printf("\n Enter any number : ");
scanf("%d",&a[0]);
max=a[0];
min=a[0];
avg=0;
for(i=1; i++;)
{
printf("\n Enter any0 Number : ");
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
if(a[i]>max)
{
max=a[i];
}
else
{
min=a[i];
}
avg=avg+a[i];

}

avg=avg/5;

printf("\n The minimum number is %d",min);
printf("\n The maximum number is %d",max);
printf("\n The average is %f",avg);

getch();

}
```

It should ask the user 5 times but it doesn't :( ?
and the output should be like.. this

Output:

Enter number: 4
Enter number: 6
Enter number: 7
Enter number: 20
Enter number: 1

Minimum is 1.
Maximum is 20.
Average is 7.6.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please indent your code. It's really hard to read this way.

Comment: What is the condition under which the for loop exits???

Answer (score 1):

your for loop is wrong

```
for(i=1; i++;)
```

this should be

```
for(i=1;i<5; i++) //because you already scanned a[0].. you need to scan till a[4]    

use avg=a[0]; instead of avg=0; 

in for loop you need to write use if (a[i]<min) instead of else
```

**Modified code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
        int i,a[5],min,max;
        float avg;
        printf("\n Enter any number : ");
        scanf("%d",&a[0]);
        max=a[0];
        min=a[0];
        avg=a[0];

        for(i=1;i<5;i++)
                {
                printf("\n Enter any0 Number : ");
                scanf("%d",&a[i]);
                if(a[i]>max)
                max=a[i];
                if( a[i]< min )
                min=a[i];

                avg=avg+a[i];

                }

                avg=avg/5;

printf("\n%d ,%d, %f\n",min,max,avg);
}
```

Comment: OMG, Thanks xo much <3 <3 <3 u saved me

Comment: i still can't do that,im new

Answer (score 0):

for(i=1; i++;) should be changed to

```
for(i=1; i<5; i++)
```

else { min=a[i]; } should be changed to

```
if (a[i] < min)
{
    min=a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong for-loop condition as mentioned in other answers.

Furthermore, you should fix the condition where you assign to the `min` variable in the for-loop. Now it's incorrect.

In addition, you're setting `avg = 0` at the beginning which is wrong. It should be `avg = a[0]`, because the average of one element equals the value of that element.